# How do I find the interior points of a set that contains an intersection?

Tags: general-topology

I have a set $D = \{(x,y)\ :\ x^2 + y^2 < 3,\ 2x + 3y = 5\}$

So I know that the interior points would be all the points in the set which don't belong to the boundary. However, when I sketch the set, i can't quite determine what the interior points are. I'm guessing that the interior points are all the points in the blue circle that don't belong in the blue and green boundaries. But I don't know if this guess is correct.

Here is a sketch of the graph :
[image]

Answer (score 4):

We have that $D$ is a subset of $L=\{(x,y): 2x+2y=5\}$ (a line !)

Then we have $int(D) \subseteq int(L)$. But $int(L) = \emptyset$.

hence, $D$ has no interior points.

Comment: Are you sure? Shouldn't the interior points be the set of points (x,y) such that x^2 + y^2 < 3, given that the points don't belong to the line 2x + 3y = 5?

Comment: Since it's an intersection, any point in D must be part of both.

Comment: @DanUznanski I'm sorry I don't think I quite understand. Are you implying that the interiors points are all the points above and below the line (but inside the circle)?

Comment: No, a point in D is part of the intersection: each such point must be part of the disk *and yes* part of the line, not *and not*.  So D is precisely the (open) segment of the line that is within the disk.